# How to set the height to a minimum of 50px but that it is flexible if there is more text

Tags: css

The required height should be 50 pixels, but if row has more text should be set more pixel. It needs to be flexible

```
.table { 
    tr:nth-child(odd){  
        background-color:rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
      }

      tr {
        height: 50px; //here is problem
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

I am try with max-height and min-height but it no work property..

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: There is no element with class `table` in your HTML, the CSS won't have any effect on your HTML.

Comment: Sorry i just copy html because in my situation is little complex table ... that is no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try by removing the height property, and in place of it write `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: Yes but now is height 57px

Answer (score 0):

you can go for minimal height with ---> `min-height: 50px;` in your css

for adjusting the divs to your text use ---> `height: fit-content;`, `height: auto;` and `display: flex;` (making it responsive)

When the text overflows in width use ---> `word-break: break-word;`  to break up the text

Comment: Ok but i need max-height 34px but if need more space set maybe height: auto ?

Comment: @fipodas you can make min-height: 34px; and the adjusting css properties to make it responsive to more text(with what i wrote). to break up text use word-break as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Set your table row as tr `height="50"` and it will treat that as the min-height.

If your content is more than `50px`, it will expand accordingly.